# Prepare for segue in TableViewDelegate methods

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, segue

[SOLVED]

Let me explain my problem;

I have a bunch of Event object which appears in tableView cells.
[image]

And these objects store in events array

```
var events: [Event]
```

Also i have another view controller(DetailViewContoller), in that view controller i have a variable for receiving event object from tableview.

```
    import UIKit

class EventDetailViewController: UIViewController {


    var event: Event?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(event?.name)
    }
```

When i tapped the cells i want to pass my current event object to variable(indicated on above) in DetailViewController. So i tried this ->

```
extension EventListViewcontroller:UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Whenever cells tapped, related object needs to pass DetailViewController
    performSegue(withIdentifier: K.Segues.eventListToDetail, sender: self)

   func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if segue.identifier == K.Segues.eventListToDetail {
          let VC = segue.destination as! EventDetailViewController
        VC.event = events[indexPath.row]
      }
  }

}
```

**But unfortunately after segue performed when i checked the event variable in DetailViewController it was shown as a nil. So question is, how can i pass my tapped event cell to other view controller?**

Note: i've found this topic [How do you test UIStoryBoard segue is triggered by didSelectRow(at:)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42373035/how-do-you-test-uistoryboard-segue-is-triggered-by-didselectrowat) but it didn't help my problem...

Comment: is your condition `if segue.identifier == K.Segues.eventListToDetail {` is true? Is control even going inside if and setting VC.event = events[indexPath.row]?

Comment: Yes it's true because when i tapped the cells it performs segue but it prints event?.name as a "nil"  :/

Comment: performing segue doesn't confirm if your condition in prepareForSegue is satisfied, put a break point inside prepareForSegue and check, I am assuming posted code is messed up here and you really have prepareForsegue as different method and not nested inside `didSelect`

Comment: @SandeepBhandari  i did put and i checked, and i realize that it doesn't trigger prepare segue at all...

Comment: Thats the bug, fix it you will have your problem solved

Comment: That's the thing, i can't fix :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class

```
class ViewController: EventListViewcontroller {
     var selectedIndex: IndexPath? = nil
}
```

And change your code in `didSelect` as

```
extension ViewController:UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Whenever cells tapped, related object needs to pass DetailViewController
        self.selectedIndex = indexPath
        performSegue(withIdentifier: K.Segues.eventListToDetail, sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let indexPath = self. selectedIndex, segue.identifier == K.Segues.eventListToDetail {
            let VC = segue.destination as! EventDetailViewController
            VC.event = events[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much Sandeep, it works. You gave me a new perspective thanks for that too...

Comment: @rutkay-karabulak: Am glad that, I could help you :)